# ZSH Syntax for splitting a string using multiple characters as delimiters

Tags: zsh

I can't find the correct syntax for doing this using the built in split operator of ZSH: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html

This works but I'm trying to get rid of the echo / sed

```
for i in *;
do f=$(echo $i | sed 's/[-.]/ /g');
parts=(${(s: :)f}); echo $parts[1]; done
```

How do I specify a character set in the expression `parts=(${(s: :)f});` ?

I'm trying to find the first alphanumeric sub string of the input string.

Comment: is `${foo//patt/repl}` what you are looking for?

Comment: so in your case it would be `${i//[.-]/ }`

Comment: you could also use this to get the array: `parts=(${=${i//[.-]/ }})`. If that is what you want I will write an answer with more explanation^^

Answer (score 2):

The `s[sep]` [parameter expansion flag](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) only takes a string (doesn't have to be a single character), not a pattern.

You can combine several `s` operators by [nesting expansions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules):

```
for file in *(N); do
  parts=( ${(@s[-])${(s[.])file}} )
  print -r The first part is $parts[1]
done
```

(also note the `(N)` [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to avoid the error if there's no non-hidden file in the current working directory).

Or you could use [IFS splitting with `$=var`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-SH_005fWORD_005fSPLIT_002c-toggle)¹:

```
IFS=.-
parts=( $=file )
```

Beware that while `parts=( ${(s[.])string} )` discards empty elements, `IFS=.; parts=( $=string )` doesn't, though you can do `parts=($=string); parts=($string)` to discard them afterwards or use an anonymous function such as `(){ parts=($@); } $=string`.

Or as you do replace all the characters with one and split on that with `s[sep]` or IFS-splitting, though you can use the ksh-style `${param//pattern/replacement}` or csh-style (with [`histsubstpattern`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-HISTSUBSTPATTERN) on) `$param:gs/pattern/replacement/`:

```
parts=( ${(s[.])file//[-...]/.} )
```

If it's just the first of those parts you need, you can just do:

```
first_part=${file%%[.-]*}
```

Like in ksh where that syntax comes from in the 80s.

If it's the first sequence of one or more alnums:

```
set -o extendedglob
first_sequence_of_alnums=${(MS)file##[[:alnum:]]##}
```

Or

```
if [[ $file =~ [[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then
  first_sequence_of_alnums=$MATCH
else
  print -ru2 "There are no alnums in $file"
fi
```

Or:

```
alnum_sequences=( ${(s[:])file//[^[:alnum:]]/:} )
if (( $#alnum_sequences > 0 )); then
  first_sequence_of_alnums=$alnum_sequences[1]
else
  print -ru2 "There are no alnums in $file"
fi
```

In any case, if you have to use [`echo`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-echo), that should rather be

```
echo -E - $file
```

Without `-E`, backslashes in `$file` could be mangled. Without `-`, that wouldn't work for values of `$file` such as `-n` `-Eneene`... With [`print`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-print): `print -r -- $file` (or `print -r - $file`). It's even more important not to forget the `--`/`-` with `print` as `print` supports more options, some of which potentially dangerous.

---

<sup>¹ Note that [it's one of the things other Bourne-like shells do by default upon unquoted parameter expansions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/FAQ/zshfaq03.html#l19), often considered a misfeature (and a [dangerous one!](/q/171346)). In zsh, you have to request that splitting explicitly with `$=var` like you have to request globbing explicitly (also done on unquoted expansions in other shells!) with `$~var` (or `$=~var` for both).</sup>

Comment: Can you comment on ZSH ' $=var '  syntax ? It's not trivial to search as you can imagine