# ZSH documentation for IFS=.- parts=( $=file )

Tags: zsh

This feature of ZSH (I presume) is used in an answer [ZSH Syntax for splitting a string using multiple characters as delimiters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773194/zsh-syntax-for-splitting-a-string-using-multiple-characters-as-delimiters)

> Or you could use IFS splitting with $=var:
>
> ```
> IFS=.-
> parts=( $=file )
> ```

Can you point to the name of this construct in the ZSH documentation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the meaning of `IFS`: “[Variables index](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Variables-Index.html#Variables-Index)” → “[`IFS`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#index-IFS)”, “[`IFS`, use of](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-IFS_002c-use-of)”, “[`IFS`, use of](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-IFS_002c-use-of-1)”, “[`IFS`, use of](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-IFS_002c-use-of-2)”.

The first “use of” link points to the documentation of `$=NAME`, which is a bit harder to find if you aren't used to zsh syntax. `$` starts [parameter expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion). Parameter expansion can take several forms, including `${=spec}`. The `spec` part can be a parameter name or a parameter name with one of various suffixes to do prefix/suffix removal, pattern replacement, default value injection, etc., which is documented in a not very clear way the first time the `spec` metavariable appears (in the documentation of `${#spec}`). Furthermore the braces are optional when `spec` is just a parameter name, which is mentioned in the documentation of `${name}` and in the documentation of `${#spec}` but also applies to `${=spec}` and such.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about `$=file` rather then the array assignment `parts=( ... )`, it's documented in the [Parameter Expansion](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) section (or equivalently in `man zshexpn`), beginning at the subsection starting `${#spec}`

> ```
>    ${=spec}
>           Perform  word splitting using the rules for SH_WORD_SPLIT during
>           the evaluation of spec, but regardless of whether the  parameter
>           appears  in  double  quotes; if the `=' is doubled, turn it off.
>           This forces parameter expansions to be split into separate words
>           before  substitution, using IFS as a delimiter.  This is done by
>           default in most other shells.
> ```

The "bare" form `$=spec` is explained under `${#spec}`:

> ```
>           If the option POSIX_IDENTIFIERS is not set, and spec is a simple
>           name, then the braces are optional; this is true even  for  spe‐
>           cial  parameters  so  e.g.  $#-  and  $#* take the length of the
>           string $- and the array $* respectively.   If  POSIX_IDENTIFIERS
>           is set, then braces are required for the # to be treated in this
>           fashion.
> ```